# How to accept time in Node js from the user

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to know how to accept a time(IST) in node js
This is the schema of my mongoose model,how to write the datatype for the time

```
module.exports = mongoose => {
    const Flight = mongoose.model(
      "flight",
      mongoose.Schema(
        {
          flight_name:String,
          from: String,
          to: String,
          date:Date,
          arrivaltime:
          departuretime:
          fare:Number

        },
      )
    );
  
    return Flight;
  };
```

Also while accepting it from the user what to write in the create flight section:

```
const db = require("../models");
const Flight = db.flights;

exports.create = (req, res) => {
    
    // Create a Flight
  const flight = new Flight({
    flight_name:req.body.flight_name,
    from: req.body.from,
    to: req.body.to,
    date: new Date(req.body.date),
    arrivaltime:
    departuretime:
    fare:req.body.fare
  });

  // Save Flight in the database
  flight
    .save(flight)
    .then(data => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Flight."
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: I can't clearly identify your problem, what do you mean by "how to accept a time"? You already seem to be using the date object and storing its string. You can store unix time for convenience, with `date.getTime()`

Comment: @Celsiuss So is it somethig that I can use date.getTime() in mongoose model as a datatype or do I need to keep it as Date itself?

Comment: always store as UTC not IST (or whatever the server is returning)